# How do I modify taxonomy term slugs dynamically?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I need to be able to modify custom taxonomy term slugs on the fly or at least display them correctly in the URL. I have looked at it from every angle I can think of, but just can't quite figure it out. I have tried rewrites which got me close, but not close enough.

Current: `domain.com/stores/store-name/`

Desired: `domain.com/stores/store-name-(string)/`

Most of the terms will be created by the hundreds and done automatically. So manually editing them is not an option.